# Filtering tabulator date column between two dates

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm trying to filter a date column in tabulator to only show records between 2 dates, but when I execute the command all records are removed from the table, displaying nothing.

The code I have.

```
function filterDuePayments() {
    var startDate = getCurrentUKDate();
    var endDate = getDate30DaysAhead();
    
    //Filter table column 'UserDate' between dates. [Date format passed to Tabulator dd/mm/yyyy]
    table.setFilter(function (data) {
        var rowDataDate = new Date(data.UserDate);
        return rowDataDate >= startDate && rowDataDate <= endDate;
    });
}


function getCurrentUKDate() {
  const today = new Date();

  // Get day, month, and year components
  const day = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0'); // Ensure two digits
  const month = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); // Months are zero-based
  const year = today.getFullYear();

  // Format as dd/mm/yyyy
  const ukDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;

  return ukDate;
}


function getDate30DaysAhead() {
  const today = new Date();
  
  // Calculate the date 30 days ahead
  const futureDate = new Date(today);
  futureDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);

  // Get day, month, and year components
  const day = String(futureDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0'); // Ensure two digits
  const month = String(futureDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); // Months are zero-based
  const year = futureDate.getFullYear();

  // Format as dd/mm/yyyy
  const ukDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;

  return ukDate;
}
```

Comment: Found a workaround, so I've added an additional hidden column to the tabulator with the date format as yyyy-mm-dd and filtering on that seems to work, it doesn't like the UK date format for some reason, even though that's what gets passed to the table from PHP as JSON